# New-WebServiceProxy cmdlet fails with "The operation has timed out" exception

Tags: asp.net, web-services, powershell, timeout, powershell-2.0

I'm deploying an ASP.NET application with PowerShell. It includes the web service, and I need to call one of its methods right after the web application is deployed. Obviously, this request will take time as it should "warm up" the website.

So, I make a plain call to `New-WebServiceProxy` to get the proxy object and then call a method:

```
$ps = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri "http://mysite/folder/myservice.asmx"
```

However, this operation takes some time and always fails with the timeout exception. I should say that it's all happening in the remote session. When the application is deployed locally (hence the script runs in a local session) the call succeeds.

I have verified the `executionTimeout` of the `<httpRuntime>` in the web.config - it has quite big timeout. But it is my assumption that it is not taken into consideration before the first call is made. So, I assume it is some property/switch of the `New-WebServiceProxy`, which should influence this behavior, but I failed to find it.

Does anyone have an idea?

P.S. I'm using PowerShell 2.0, but if the solution is there in v3.0, it is acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround I ended up with is warming up the website after deployment and before calling the web method. Something like this (works with PowerShell 2.0 as well):

```
$request = [system.net.WebRequest]::Create("http://mysite")
$request.Timeout = 2400000   # some big enough timeout goes here
$request.GetResponse() | Out-Null
```

After this, the call to `New-WebServiceProxy` succeeds and it's possible to call the web method.

Comment: This is nice. Invoke-WebRequest has some kind of dependency on internet explorer (so you have to setup IE atleast once with your concrete user), while this solution doesn't require anything.

Answer (score 2):

If the issue is indeed a timeout, then try this approach on PowerShell V3:

```
$wr = Invoke-WebRequest http://mysite/folder/myservice.asmx?wsdl -TimeoutSec 30
$wr.Content | Out-File -enc utf8 c:\myservice.wsdl
$ps = New-WebServiceProxy file:///c:\myservice.wsdl
```

BTW your problem could be the missing `?wsdl` on the URI

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Keith! This workaround works. The problem was not in `?wsdl`, I verified that. Actually, the trick here is in warming up the site by `Invoke-WebRequest`. If you omit the line #2 and run `New-WebServiceProxy` with the original URL - it works as well. I ended up with a similar work around for my case. Thank you again.

Comment: Keith, if you think my workaround below is worse than the one you suggested, please let me know. I'm not that good in PowerShell yet...

Comment: @YanSklyarenko That is a fine workaround for V2.  I just didn't have the time last night to mess around with what the API calls would be on V2.